# keep focus in one column of table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, focus

Here is my [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yf31pn?file=src/app/focus-monitor-focus-via-example.html)

```
<table class="example-focus-monitor" cdkTrapFocus>
  <tr>  
    <th><button>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button><button>also focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button><button>also focus</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- I want to keep the focus only on the right column. So it should go from top to bottom if I keep pressing tab.
- I basically want to SKIP focus on 'dont focus'-buttons

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tabindex='-1'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). A negative value indicate that  element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation.

```html
<p>my Table</p>
<table class="example-focus-monitor" cdkTrapFocus>
  <tr>  
    <th><button tabIndex='-1'>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button tabIndex='-1'>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button><button>also focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button tabIndex='-1'>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button tabIndex='-1'>dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button>focus</button><button>also focus</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>should never be focused when using tab and focus inside table</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **tabindex** attribute specifies the tab order of an element (when the "tab" button is used for navigating). Assigning  a **negative** value will make it unfocusable.

Try like this:

```
  <tr>  
    <th><button tabindex="-1">dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button tabindex="1">focus</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><button  tabindex="-1">dont focus</button></th>
    <th><button tabindex="2">focus</button><button>also focus</button></th>
  </tr>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yf31pn-stuita?embed=1&file=src/app/focus-monitor-focus-via-example.html)**

Comment: thank you @Adrita. Is there any reason why u explicitely set the tabIndex on the other elements? (tabindex="2" ... etc)? brks solution just works fine.

Comment: In case you want to define which button to focus after which one. Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_tabindex

Comment: aah okay. you where thinking ahead. In my case the natural next focus is the one I want. Super cool :-)